# Why do I still get "A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected" even after disabling it?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I've just created a new MVC4 "Internet" application in Visual Studio 2012 (C#).

I went to the default /Account/Login page and typed in `<b />` as the username.

The server crashed with this error:

> A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (UserName="
> ").

I've seen it before and got rid of it before, so I can do it again easily. I changed my [Web.config](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web.config) to look like this:

```
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" requestValidationMode="2.0" /><!-- Look here -->
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
<pages validateRequest="false"><!-- Look here -->
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
</system.web>
```

I cleaned the solution and did a rebuild, but I still get exactly the same error when I try `<br />` again.

What's wrong?

Comment: If you had read the entire error message on the page you would have noticed the URL to the microsoft KB article describing how to disable input validation for MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying the Web.config file is how you would disable the setting in Web Forms.

In MVC you would apply the `ValidateInput` attribute to your controller method.

```
<HttpPost>
<ValidateInput(False)>
Public Function ActionName(model As Object) As ActionResult

End Function
```

Or if you prefer C#

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
ActionResult ActionName(Object model) {

}
```

Comment: According to [Request Validation in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh882339.aspx): "To disable request validation in an ASP.NET MVC application, you must [...]" `<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />`.

Comment: You have got to READ.  READ what that setting does.  That's just one step in the process.

Comment: Indeed. I've read through the article, but nothing makes it overly clear as to why this method is wrong or which method is best to make this behaviour global. However, your answer is correct. I'm going to use global filters to apply this application-wide.

Comment: The `requestValidationMode="2.0"` causes the validation for the input to be moved to a later point on the processing pipeline.  ASP.NET 4 validated the input much earlier in the pipeline.  Allowing the input to be processed later in the pipeline enables the other parts of the process, like the `ValidateInputAttribute`.